# Node.js body-parser not working after installation

Tags: node.js, npm-install, body-parser

After using npm install and updating my json package, the body-parser still gives an error about needing to install the middleware.

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

Answer (score 0):

Body-parser parses your request and converts it into a format from which you can easily extract relevant information that you may need. First of all require the following in your app.js file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

and add the following line to make it work

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```